# How can I extract values from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My column has different length values and I want to extract all the values that are before the 2nd dash.
Here are some of the values in the column

```
1AA-00001-20170101
AAAA-10010-20161201
1BBB2-22222-20151105
```

How do I get the following values in SQL

```
1AA-00001
AAAA-10010
1BBB2-22222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your strings seems pretty canonical.  It seems you can do:

```
select left(col, len(col) - 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT LEFT(col, CHARINDEX( '-', col, CHARINDEX('-', col)+1)-1)
FROM table;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/SVD65631)**

Comment: I think you are missing a `+ 1` somewhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fixed :)

Comment: @jackstraw22, the inside (second) charindex finds the location of the first dash. The outside (first) charindex finds a dash, starting at the location just found. If you don't add +1 to that location, it will find the first one again, which is not what we want here, we want the second dash.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
-- sample data
declare @table table (somestring varchar(100));
insert @table 
values ('1AA-00001-20170101'), ('AAAA-10010-20161201'),('1BBB2-22222-20151105');

-- solution
select somestring, newstring = 
         parsename(replace(somestring,'-','.'),3)+'-'+
         parsename(replace(somestring,'-','.'),2)
from @table;
```

**Results**

```
somestring            newstring
--------------------- ------------
1AA-00001-20170101    1AA-00001
AAAA-10010-20161201   AAAA-10010
1BBB2-22222-20151105  1BBB2-22222
```